# Custom receiver connection failed

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have an Android app, working with a custom receiver. It was working without problem, but with the release of the new cast companion library, I decided to upgrade it, as well as my Play services version.

Anyway, when I try to connect to Chromecast, my custom receiver HTML page is displayed. But then, I can't connect and send data to it. After a while (something like 15 seconds), the app exits on the Chromecast.

Then, I've tried to get the Cast Hello Text sample to work, using the same app id. Same problem here.

Here is the code I use to launch the Cast app:

```
Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, getString(R.string.app_id), true)
```

The result I receive in the ResultCallback, is a status with code 15, with isSuccess method returning false.

The problem doesn't seem to come from my Chromecast, since other users have the exact same issue.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Lol, this seems to be the same problem as I have over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558778/cast-connection-timeout Could you double check, maybe we have the same issue? If so, either we're both doing something wrong, or it's a bug in the new library as you said it used to work before you upgraded. Could somebody from the Google Cast relations team take a closer look at these issues, as it's starting to get mildly frustrating... ?

Comment: Have you tried the Cast Hello Text sample app with its own receiver and not your apps receiver?

Comment: Yes, I used the sample receiver app. Didn't work either.

Comment: So this isn't related to CCL since Cast Hello Text app doesn't use that. You can file a bug if you provide logs: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list

Comment: I'm starting to think this bug also affects the Twitch app, which has had problems with disconnects for the last few months. I would cast Twitch, just to be disconnected after a couple of seconds, pretty much the same way @Aerilys describes here and also how I encounter it in my own test app. Are you trying to tell me you guys haven't received *any* reports on this matter at all for the past few weeks/months? This is outrageous...

Comment: @LeonNicholls Yes that was my guess too. I've tried with an old version of my code (which was certainly working at this time), and it's still isn't working, so I guess it's due to a change on the Chromecast side.

Comment: File a bug with sender and receiver logs: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list

Comment: Submited issue #567, @Aerilys can you add your own logs maybe inside a comment over at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=567&sort=-id ?

Comment: Hey @Aerilys, I read all that IssueTracker thread and was unable to find a conclusive answer. I'm still facing the same problem, but I tried with the published Id you reported in the thread: 'B0BDC472', and you manage to make it work. Could you please update your answer to enlighten me and others who might be passing through the same problem? Thank you very much.